# How to annotate field without duplicate fields django

Tags: django, django-models, django-orm

So I basically have this simple model:

```
class BaseLesson(models.Model):
    YOUTUBE_VIDEO = '0'
    MARKDOWN = '1'

    TYPE_CHOICES = (
        (YOUTUBE_VIDEO, 'youtube-video'),
        (MARKDOWN, 'markdown'),
    )

    type = models.CharField(
        max_length=10, choices=TYPE_CHOICES, default=MARKDOWN, verbose_name=_('type'))

    shown_users = models.ManyToManyField(
        User, related_name='lessons', verbose_name=_('shown users'), blank=True)

    objects = managers.BaseLessonManager()
```

There is a many-to-many relationship with the User model in shown_users

And I wanna annotate the is_shown status based on the many-to-many table, so I did this:

```
class BaseLessonManager(InheritanceManager, CachingManager):
    def get_lesson_with_is_shown(self, user):
    
        shown_user_case = django_models.Case(
            django_models.When(shown_users__id=user.id,
                               then=django_models.Value(True)),
            default=django_models.Value(False),
            output_field=django_models.BooleanField())

        return self.get_queryset().annotate(
            is_shown=shown_user_case)
```

The problem with this is that if user1 and user2 saw the same lesson it will be duplicate, for example:

```
+-----------------+-----------+
|    lesson_id    |  user_id  |
+-----------------+-----------+
|        1        |     1     |
|        1        |     2     |
|        1        |     3     |
+-----------------+-----------+
```

For such case, I will get these duplicated lessons:

```
            {
                "id": 1
                "type": "0",
                "is_shown": true
            },
            {
                "id": 1
                "type": "0",
                "is_shown": false
            },
            {
                "id": 1
                "type": "0",
                "is_shown": false
            }
```

So it's checking **each related lesson field** in the SHOWN_USERS table... sample photo:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/y2igr.jpg

### What I tried so far:

#### 1. Exclude:

I added an exclude expression to get rid of the extra lessons:

```
return self.get_queryset().annotate(
       is_shown=shown_user_case).exclude(
       django_models.Q(is_shown=False) & django_models.Q(shown_users__id=user.id))
```

And I think this is super ugly cuz if I have 1000 users and 50 lessons it means I'm taking all 50000 fields then filter 50 of them :(

Is there any cleaner way to do that ?

#### 2. Distinct:

I have tried distinct before and it's not fixing the problem, instead of shown the lesson three times it will show:

- once (is_shown = True),
- and another time (is_shown = False)

Comment: did u try `.distinct()` with the name of the field you want to be unique? looks like in your case `.distinct('lesson_id')`

Comment: Note - above recipe will work only with`PostgreSQL`

Comment: I have tried distinct before and it's not fixing the problem, instead of shown the lesson three times it will show it once (is_shown = True), and another time (is_shown = False) :(

Comment: What field do u use distinct on?

Comment: I just added distinct at the end of the query since I'm running in development (sqlite), but as I said let's say we have two repeated lessons... it will basically take one of them as (is_shown=True) and another one as (is_shown=False).



I tried to tackle this using prefetch_related(shown_users) with a filter based on id... same result !

Comment: Try as I said `.distinct('lesson_id')` or whatever field name do u have.

Comment: But I will have a production PostgreSql db when I deploy... I can't install PostgreSql server on the development environment just to test one single query... do you have any trick to test that without installing PostgreSql server ?

Comment: Actually distinct perfectly works with PostgreSQL, this is noticed in Django docs. Usually I use it as I have written.

Comment: What exactly is your `get_lesson_with_is_shown` supposed to be doing? It seems it's setting `is_shown=True` whenever the passed in user's id is equal to the id of the _intermediary m2m table_ (`shown_users__id=user.id`). Which doesn't seem to make sense?

Comment: No, it does make sense... cuz **only** those who saw the lesson will be on the `shown_users` table (if he didn't see it, he ain't on the table thus False), do you have any other way of finding out who saw the lesson ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I managed to fix the problem, and If figured out that my way of querying many-to-many is the problem, instead of `shown_users__id == user.id` I used `id__in==user.lessons.values('id')`, full code:

```
class BaseLessonManager(InheritanceManager, CachingManager):
    def with_is_shown(self, user):

        user_shown_lessons = user.lessons.values('id')

        shown_user_case = django_models.Case(
            django_models.When(id__in=user_shown_lessons,
                           then=django_models.Value(True)),
            default=django_models.Value(False),
            output_field=django_models.BooleanField())

        return self.get_queryset().annotate(
            is_shown=shown_user_case)
```